# Child div horizontally scrollable but fix parent window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html, css question.
I'd like to make child div horizontally scrollable but parent window unscrollable.

Currently, the following is the code.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="div1">
        ...
    </div>

    <div id="div2" style="overflow-x:scroll; width:2000px">
        <img src="1.png"/>
        <img src="2.png"/>
        <img src="3.png"/>
        <img src="4.png"/>
        <img src="5.png"/>
        <img src="6.png"/>
        <img src="7.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when scroll div2, it will make the whole window to scroll.

The following is the schematic diagram.

[image]

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it overflow, the content must be larger than the div, not the div itself. and to be able to make it inline, you must use `display:inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`. Let me know if you have concerns.

Check out the fiddle below.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Abpy/1/)

**CSS**

```
#div2{
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I don't think display:inline-block; is needed. It's certainly not in your Fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/3Abpy/2/

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to click the green check button. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow:hidden;` to your parent div and `overflow-x: auto;` to your child div.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable scrolling for the `html` or `body` element. Not entirely sure that's what you wish to do, but either that or the `#parent` element.

```
html,body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

or

```
#parent{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Additionally right now your `#div2` is wider than most screens, so you won't get a scroll bar for it likely, so you might be intending to scroll the `#parent` element?

Additionally it is enough to set the `overflow` to `auto` instead of `scroll` as `scroll` just forces a scrollbar to be visible even if there is no content to scroll.